# Save as menu is disable for custom graph editor

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have added two menu in my RCP application Save and Save As. If my custom editor is dirty then save option is enable but save as option is disable. Save As option is enable for other .java, .properties etc file but not for custom graph editor. Observe for manifest custom editor also it is disable in eclipse. So may be Save As is disable for custom editor.

So how to enable this option i have tried registering this action into graph but this wont work.

Extension Added as below:

```
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">
         <menu
               id="hg.ui.graphbuilder.menus.file"
               label="File">
            --------
            --------
            <command
                  commandId="org.eclipse.ui.file.save"
                  icon="icons/save_o.png"
                  label="Save"
                  style="push">
            </command>
            <command
                  commandId="org.eclipse.ui.file.saveAs"
                  icon="icons/saveAs_o.png"
                  label="Save As..."
                  style="push">
            </command>
    -----------
    -----------
</extension>
```

Comment: Well does your editor implement `ISaveablePart`? What does it have for the `isSaveAsAllowed` method?

Comment: I am using GEF3 API for that so implemented using GraphicalEditorWithFlyoutPalette which internally extended form GraphicalEditor.

Comment: Just checked GraphicalEditor haven't provided default implementation for this and returning the false for isSaveAsAllowed. Thanks @greg-449 for input.